# Can I turn off the Apple Pencil auto-adjust feature for highlighting text?

Tags: ipad, highlights, apple-pencil

I noticed on my new iPad that I can use the Pencil to highlight text (say, for copy/pasting), just like one can do with a finger. However, using my finger, while dragging the edge of the highlight region, I can be very precise about where I want the highlighted area to end. For example, I can make it end in the middle of a word.

But with the Pencil, this is impossible. The region always slides left or right until it reaches the end of a full word. This is a bit annoying for me since I am composing in LaTeX and often need to copy/paste parts of equations that begin and end in precise places that the pencil doesn’t permit.

The easy fix is to just use my finger, but I like the pencil. Is there a setting that can change this behavior?